# JPA-annotated POJOs are not mapped correctly when @Column is not used for all members

Tags: java, spring, jooq

I have a custom POJO on which I am mapping the database records using JOOQ `.fetchInto(TestClassDto.class)`. Most of the fields in my POJO are exactly similar to a database table's columns. However, there are a few that are different, therefore, I added java persistence and used `@Column` to explicitly map such columns on my POJO as described [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos/#N8C7DE).

Unfortunately, this is not working if I use @Column on a few specific fields. Only the fields that are annotated with `@Column` are mapped and the rest are ignored and set `Null` even though they are similar to the table column name and should be mapped implicitly.

Could you give me a hint if I am missing anything?

Sample POJO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestClassDto {

    @Column(name = "field_AB_XYZ") // explicit mapping is required, thus need @Column
    private Long myfieldAB;

    /* Here, mapping could be implicitly done without using @Column because 
    ** database column name and POJO property is same but it stays empty if I 
    ** ignore @Column */
    @Column(name = "hello_world") 
    private Long helloWorld;

}
```

Lastly, If I completely remove `@Column` from POJO's properties, `helloWorld` property is filled (implicitly) but `myfieldAb` remains `NULL` (because mapping is not found as expected).

Below is sample query:

```
dslContext.select()
      .from(SOMETHING)
      .where(SOMETHING.NAME.eq("Something"))
      .fetchInto(TestClassDto.class)
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace of the NPE?

Comment: Sorry, just realized that NPE was irrelevant. But the problem remains the same. Now, I don't get NPE anymore but mapping is still not working. I have updated my question.

Comment: Where is your @entity annotation?

Comment: @SpasojePetronijević I dont need `@Entity` because I am mapping to DTO and to map unknown columns from table to pojo, JOOQ only supports `@Column` annotation. here-> https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos/#N8C7DE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.15, you either have to annotate

- *all* of your attributes...
- *none* of your attributes...

... with the `@Column` annotation. There's a pending feature request to mimick JPA more closely and make the `@Column` annotation optional for some attributes: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4586.

In the meantime, instead of using those JPA annotations, you could add auxiliary getters/setters for your column:

```java
public void setFieldAbXyz(Long v) {
    this.myfieldAB = v;
}

public Long getFieldAbXyz() {
    return myfieldAB;
}
```